# how can I transform a equation into $y=a\sin(\omega t + \Delta)$ form?

Tags: trigonometry

$y=5(\sin 3\pi t + \sqrt{3}\cos 3\pi t)$ how can I transform this equation into $y=a\sin(\omega t + \Delta)$ form?(Here $a,\omega,\Delta$ are constants and $t$ is a variable)

Comment: $\displaystyle\sqrt{\,3\,}\, = \tan\left(\pi \over 3\right)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using $\sin{(a +b)} = \sin{a}\cos{b} + \sin{b}\cos{b}$, this simplifies to $10\sin{(3\pi t + \pi /3)}$.

Comment: how have you got it?

Comment: I have realised..thanks

Comment: Using the identity. $a=3\pi t$ and $b=\pi /3$